# How to boot from new partition after do dd

Tags: boot, partition, btrfs, fdisk

I have 10 partition. My root (`/`) partition located on `/dev/sda9` and my home (`/home`) partition located on `/dev/sda2`.

I want to move my root partition (`/dev/sda9`) to `/dev/sda5`. So I copy my root partition to `/dev/sda5` use command

```
sudo dd bs=4M if=/dev/sda9 of=/dev/sda5 status=progress
```

After I run this command I got:

```
$ lsblk -f

sda                                                                                          
├─sda1  ext4     1.0   EXT4sannRoot      a75c6f17-64e9-45c4-9147-7902dfe976af                
├─sda2  ext4     1.0   EXT4sannHome      8b402a67-e51d-46fd-866c-e974c9fbcb5b  124,8G    37% /home
├─sda3  swap     1                       3deea589-4946-47b4-8a62-fe9297dcf447                [SWAP]
├─sda4  vfat     FAT32                   B960-8CA5                             234,4M     7% /boot/efi
├─sda5  btrfs                            3f8da5ce-c652-41b6-b7a2-9dae87c1a637                
├─sda7  ext4     1.0   PrimeOS           e5d445e4-f59f-5158-b9c7-465f7009bc23                
├─sda8  btrfs          BTRFSsannExternal f77bddfe-f013-4629-9929-bf589a1591a5                
├─sda9  btrfs                            3f8da5ce-c652-41b6-b7a2-9dae87c1a637   12,6G    63% /
└─sda10 ext4     1.0   Dokumen           6fc80ec7-f9f9-43ff-ae69-8895d0f1a3a4    7,3G    20% /home/sann/Dokumen
```

I got the same partition UUID between `sda9` and `sda5`.

The Question. How to get boot from `/dev/sda5` instead of `/dev/sda9` in the next boot.

Comment: You need to update your bootloader configuration file, whatever you use (lilo / grub) and change the references to the old root partition (device / label / UUID) for adequate references of the new. (you could also add them and offer the choice in a menu)

Answer (score 1):

I solved this after:

1. Change my btrfs UUID to random by running `btrfstune -u /dev/sdaX`. Example:
   `btrfstune -u /dev/sda5`
2. Then edit the fstab on `/dev/sda5` in `/etc/fstab`
3. And because I enable os-prober. I can easily run `sudo update-grub`
4. Edit the root UUID on `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`. Then copy it and paste on `/dev/sda5` `grub.cfg`
5. Boot to `/dev/sda5`. Then run `sudo update-grub`

Because I want to use `/dev/sda5` as grub host instead of `/dev/sda9`, I do:

```
$ sudo grub-install /dev/sda5
$ sudo update-grub
```

BTW, I am use UEFI/GPT